# AIX: how to do a dump that contains the application related infos too?

Tags: memory, aix, dump

There is a server having an interesting problem (a few other had the problem too). We think that SAP takes almost all the paging, but we cannot say that 100%, because when this problem occurs, even a "ps -ef" won't run on the system because the command will hang!

During the problem (before a reboot, because a reboot fixes the problem), how can I do a dump, that the developers later can analyze?

So far I read that if a:

```
sysdumpstart -p
```

is executed the AIX will do a dump and reboot after it:

```
-p  Initiates a system dump and writes the results to the primary dump device.
```

**Question: but is this enough?** (the "sysdumpstart -p" command) Will it creates a dump that will store the SAP related infos too, to later debug?

```
12:root@SERVER:/root # sysdumpdev -l
primary              /dev/lg_dumplv
...
12:root@SERVER:/root # sysdumpdev -e
Estimated dump size in bytes: 4660710604
12:root@SERVER:/root #
```

The lg_dumplv is 12288 MByte sized, so it should be enough.

After the reboot, I will find the dump files in the "/var/adm/ras/vmcore.x" ? Or there is an additional command to put the dump to the FS from the dump lv?

Comment: wouldn't the periodic nmon logging help you easily highlight the offending process ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sysdumpstart -p
```

it took about ~22 minutes to do this 4 GByte sized one. It automatically reboots after the dump! After reboot, save the dump from the dumpLV to a file.

```
smitty dump
Copy a system dump from a dump device to a file
```

trying to get a developer who can analyze the dump file :) opening software call.

How to force a system dump:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1019210